# How to add a copy of an existing library in Add-on Builder

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm having some problems integrating libraries to the Libraries-folder in Mozilla's Add-on Builder:

Few weeks ago I wrote a library and was only able to add it to one of my add-ons when the library was public. Now I suddenly can add it even though it's been made private(!?)
I would like to modify an existing library (Erik Vold's toolbarbutton). So I made a copy, modified it, and now I would like to use it. But no matter if it's private or public I can't find it clicking on the + next to "Libraries" and entering the exact name.
Same goes for another library that I created myself...
So I feel like twisting a wheel of fortune here. Sometimes it works - most times it doesn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with the builder that we hope to resolve soon:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=777352

Sorry I don't currently have a better answer!

Comment: Ah, that's a good answer since it saves me some hours of searching for a solution ;}  I try using the SDK now... Thank You